# CQL - find related rows in the same table?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I am new to CQL. Using Cassandra 3.x
I have a basic university class table as

```
Class_ID         INT
Class_Name       VARCHAR
Class_Date       TIMESTAMP
Class_TimeHour   INT
```

Sample entries are

```
{1,"Bio 1","01/01/2018","700"}
{2,"MC 1" ,"01/01/2018","700"}
{3,"Bio 2","01/01/2018","815"}
{3,"MC 2" ,"01/01/2018","1100"}
```

700 represents 0700 hours in 24 hour notation.

I need to answer some basic queries, please advise on how to best setup the table and queries.

1. Can i get a Class_TimeHour desc ordered list of classes?
2. Can i get a Class_TimeHour desc ordered list of a particular class. Does this mean i need to setup a partition key differently from #1 ?
3. Can i get a list of all Class_Name that are within 60 min window of each other. My results from above should be

   {1,"Bio 1","01/01/2018","700"}
   {2,"MC 1","01/01/2018","700"}
   {3,"Bio 2","01/01/2018","815"}
4. How many times does "Bio 1" occur per day
5. Count of how many Class_Name       contain "MC" literal.

Thanks!